# Restrict routes in Meteor.js to privileged users

Tags: security, meteor

How do you apply the security principles for routing?

That has to be done client side. Does it mean there is no secure way to restrict some routes to specific users. I know about filters in Meteor.Router, but those are defined on the client side.

---

This is a question asked in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849529/simple-user-checking-in-meteor-is-this-secure/17850018?noredirect=1#comment26094537_17850018) by [curious2learn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316357/curious2learn).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're right, currently there's no secure way to restrict routes to specific users.

In the current version of Meteor, the whole client code is sent to all users at once. It means that all the views and templates are there, and an inclined user will find a way to display them.

This of course does not mean that you shouldn't secure them so that an unprivileged user doesn't enter them by accident, you can do this easily by router filters or by packing the whole template in a conditional. This just means that you shouldn't trust who sees the template, so you shouldn't put a hardcoded sensitive data in one. Again, **never trust the client**, even your own code (it can be tampered).

The only thing you can control is the data that will be fetched and displayed in said template.

Comment: Well would be interest how Meteor solve this in the future since one of their philosophy principles is `data only in the wired` so if they restrict some `template` access and you have to `request` them after all the content has load, that would break their rule. So maybe the Route its gonna end working on the server side?

Comment: @ncubica I'm not sure they will solve it in the future, I'm also not convinced there's anything to be solved, technically speaking? Keep in mind all a determined user can do is see the *template* of the 'restricted' route - they can't access any data assuming you've secured it on the server. So they won't be able to access anything truly private. I guess there is a scenario whereby you could have lots of static text/instructions on a template that you might not want to be public - but there are technically ways around that.

Comment: I can think in couple edge cases where you still dont want to share your design template, but I guess if is that your concern you shouldn't been using `meteor` at first as solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [Accounts Admin UI](https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3) package.  It manages the [Roles](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/roles) package which is neatly integrated with Meteor accounts.  By default Roles is not published to the Client. The [Accounts Admin UI](https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3) contains a quickstart and notes on how to integrate with Iron Router.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this two resources.
1.https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles
2.https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-roles-package/

Hope they help

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://atmospherejs.com/aumel/security-authorization which is doing the job (with server side permission checks) and is based on the popular https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles